# How to get the Picture In Picture close button event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, picture-in-picture

[image: screenshot]

How to get the Picture In Picture close button event in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

There's an event for leaving picture-in-picture, rather than the button click itself.

```js
video.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', doSomething);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/leavepictureinpicture_event